# C4204: nonstandard extension used: non-constant aggregate initializer

Tags: c++, warnings, compiler-warnings, unions

I get the warning *C4204: nonstandard extension used: non-constant aggregate initializer* for the line `union {float f; uint_fast32_t i;} u = {x};` in the following function.

```
static inline int  __ef (float x)
{
union {float f; uint_fast32_t i;} u = {x};
#if defined( _C_ ) || defined( _C1_ )
        return (u.i >> 4) & 0xff;
#else
        return (u.i >> 3) & 0xff;
#endif
}
```

How can I mitigate that warning.

Comment: The warning means that you are compiling the program as a C program instead of a C++ program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4204?view=vs-2019

> With Microsoft extensions (/Ze), you can initialize aggregate types
> (arrays, structures, unions, and classes) with values that are not
> constants.
>
> ...
>
> **Such initializations are invalid under ANSI compatibility (/Za)**.

You can disable the warning with `#pragma warning(disable:4204)`

Comment: Is disabling the solution because nothing wrong with the code? or just disable because it works?

Comment: You are using something not standard; Hence the warning. If the code is to be portable, it won't work in other compilers. If you only want to use it in VC, you may want to disable the warning.